# Static field in C# finalizer

Tags: c#

I would like to make a DisposableHelper class, that logs information in case the object was finalized (and not disposed)

```
public abstract class DisposableBase : IDisposable
{
    static Log log = new Log();
    ...

    ~DisposableBase()
    {
        log.Error("Object not disposed.");
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

`log` is a class based on log4net.
I wanted to ask if the `log` object will be accessible during the finalizer. My guess is that the static field will be garbage collected at the end of the process, but I am not sure. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, `static Log log` will not be collected and will be accessible during the finalizer

Comment: Why do you need a finalizer in first place? If this class is meant to be the base class for Disposables, you don't need a Finalizer for that. Finalizer makes sense only when you're working with some unmanaged resource.

Comment: The code i provided is not full. Actually it is wrapped in `#if DEBUG` and its goal is to find places where the consumer forget to dispose any disposable object

Comment: Ok, if this code is meant to be used only in debug environment, your code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is that the static field will be garbage collected at the end
>   of the process, but I am not sure

Not exactly. It will be eligible to garbage collection when the AppDomain is teared down. For applications with single AppDomain, it is typically when process exits.

Note that I said *eligible to garbage collection* and not *will be garbage collected*. Because that [depends on several reasons](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/).

That being said, you can access `log` field without worrying. Static fields are accessible in a finalizer(though I'd avoid it).